# Asynchronous add element to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a problem in Asp.net C#, **.net 3.5**

I have the code below :

```
List<object> objectList = new List<object>();

foreach(var item in listItem)
{
  object obj = getData (item);
  objectList.add(obj);
}
Console.Write("Finish all");
```

Each time `getData (item);` fires it takes about 1s;

I want all items in `ListItem` to run at the same time (here is `getData(item)`) and then execute after foreach finishes the `Console.write("Finish all")`.

How can I do that?
Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, and does `getData()` provide an asynchronous version at all?

Comment: do you want foreach statement to run parallel?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: i'm using .net 3.5, on top off question.
getData(item) just get from server, server response too slow, so that i want to parallel

Comment: @ daryal: yes, i want to run parallel, with each item i will get one obj and this obj will be add to objectList

Comment: Can you not change your logic of "get data from server" to handle async call backs and then add item to the list in your call back? You can process multiple requests faster.

Comment: @user2006210: Ah, missed that. If it's getting data from a server, it should be feasible to make that asynchronous. But in .NET 3.5, it's harder to do all of this nicely...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: the answer of Ilari Mäkimattila below work good for me, i want to share it with you if you need, and i'm very happy for all of your help. Hope you will help me for many question later if i have, once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
int itemCount = listItem.Length;
List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
ManualResetEvent[] resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[itemCount];

for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    var item = listItem[i];

    resetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((object index) =>
    {
        object obj = getData(item);

        lock (objectList)
            objectList.add(obj);

        resetEvents[(int)index].Set();
    }), i);
}

WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents);
Console.Write("Finish all");
```

The ThreadPool will run the task in background and the current thread will wait for all workers to finish with the ManualResetEvent.

Comment: Hope you will help me for later.

Comment: Ilari Mäkimattila: thank you very much, i have an accident for long time, so i can't mark your answer as accepted. Now, i want to say thank you again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use Parallel.ForEach / For to execute getData for all items asynchronously. Paralle.ForEach / For wont return until all iterations are completed.

Now that you add comment about using .net 3.5 my answer could be ommited.

Answer (score 1):

Hi just run this Console Application code and compare the results using foreach and Parallel.Foreach. Basically Parallel is useful in a long running tasks or those tasks that consume too much time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
            var listItem = new List<Person> { new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Person 1" }, new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Person 2" }, new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Person 3" } , new Person { Id = 4, Name = "Person 4" } };
            var start = DateTime.Now;
            var parallelList = listItem;
            //using foreach
            foreach (var item in listItem)
            {
                object obj = getData(item);
                objectList.Add(obj);
            }
            var end = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds;
            Console.Write("\nUsing foreach...Finish all in " + end + " second \n");

            start = DateTime.Now;
            //using Parallel
            Parallel.ForEach(parallelList, item =>
            {
                object obj = getData(item);
                objectList.Add(obj);
            });
            end = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds;
            Console.Write("Using Parallel...Finish all in "+ end +" second");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static object getData(Person item)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return "Test Object " + item.Id;
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: That's why sometimes getting latest technology is better. This approach is also suggested by krajew4 as you have noticed